# return specific content with regex

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have the query below where is captured the 3 largest memory consuming processes on the machine, I would like my select to display only the pid and name of the process that is contained in `{name: }`

**SELECT NORMAL EXIT**

```
top_mem   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
12555, {memory_percent: 3.6073870265949464, name: code},10581, {memory_percent: 5.82421985505014, name: VirtualBoxVM},11518, {memory_percent: 13.986433224706513, name: java}
```

**SELECT EXPECTED EXIT (MATRIZ)**

```
12555, code
10581, VirtualBoxVM
11518, java
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT top_mem FROM tbl_top_consum_hosts WHERE (top_mem regexp '^name[a-z]')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string in parts:

```
SELECT c[1], c[2]
FROM (SELECT regexp_split_to_array(p, ',.*name: ') AS c
      FROM regexp_split_to_table(top_mem, '},') AS parts(p)) AS q;
```